# I don't see any syntax errors but I keep getting ModelForm has no model class specified

Tags: django, forms, model, valueerror

I am trying to link a form to a model of mine, but i keep getting a value error on the page.  I don't see any syntax errors, and I'm not sure where the flaw in logic might be.

I already tried changing meta to Meta, it had no effect.  I already have some entities in the table could that be causing the issue?

```
# URLS________
path('posts/create_post/', views.create_post, name='create_post'),


#MODELS________
class Posts(models.Model):
    priority = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    client = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    assigned_to = models.ForeignKey(Users, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    exp_comp_time = models.FloatField(max_length=4)
    percent_comp = models.FloatField(max_length=4)
    post_date = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    due_date = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    latest_mod = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True)

class PostsForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class meta:
        model = Posts
        fields = '__all__' 


#VIEWS________
def create_post(request):
    """"Renders the create task page"""
    if request.method == "GET":
        form = PostsForm()
        return render(request, 'app/form.html', {'form': form})
    elif request.method == "POST":
        form = PostsForm(request.POST)
        form.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/posts')


#FORM.html________
{% extends "app/layout.html" %}

{% block content %}

<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
    <button type="submit">Submit Task</button>
</form>

{% endblock %}
```

The post form page should be loading.

```
Traceback:

File "C:\DjangoWebProject1\DjangoWebProject1\office_proj_env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner
  34.             response = get_response(request)

File "C:\DjangoWebProject1\DjangoWebProject1\office_proj_env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  115.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, 
request)

File "C:\DjangoWebProject1\DjangoWebProject1\office_proj_env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
 113.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args,**callback_kwargs)

File "C:\DjangoWebProject1\DjangoWebProject1\app\views.py" in create_post
 81.         form = PostsForm()

File "C:\DjangoWebProject1\DjangoWebProject1\office_proj_env\lib\site-packages\django\forms\models.py" in __init__
 285.             raise ValueError('ModelForm has no model class 
 specified.')

Exception Type: ValueError at /posts/create_post/
Exception Value: ModelForm has no model class specified.
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to capitalize `Meta`:

```
from django.forms import ModelForm    ### Double check your import statement
from django.db import models

...

class PostsForm(ModelForm):           ### Notice that I have changed the inherited class name
    class Meta:                       ### HERE
        model = Posts
        fields = '__all__'
```

> I already tried changing meta to Meta

Make sure you save the file after you make the change.

> I already have some entities in the table could that be causing the issue?

No.

Last thing to check is to make sure that your model is defined above the matching form.

Comment: Solved, I think I just needed to reset the server.